# Count number of words in a string

Tags: regex

How can I match the number of words in a string to be > then 5 using regex?

`Input1: stack over flow => the regex will not match anything`

`Input2: stack over flow stack over => the regex will match this string`

I have tried counting the spaces with `/\/s/` but that didn't really helped me, because I need to match only strings with no of words > 5

Also I don't want to use `split` by spaces.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would rely on a whitespace/non-whitespace patterns and allow trailing/leading whitespace:

```
^\s*\S+(?:\s+\S+){4,}\s*$
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/rZ0xO6/2)

Explanation:

- `^` - start of string
- `\s*` - optional any number of whitespace symbols
- `\S+` - one or more non-whitespace symbols
- `(?:\s+\S+){4,}` - 4 or more sequences of one or more whitespace symbols followed with one or more non-whitespace symbols
- `\s*` - zero or more (optional) trailing whitespace symbols
- `$` - end of string

Answer (score 5):

```
^ *\w+(?: +\w+){4,}$
```

You can use this regex.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/cZ0sD2/15

Answer (score 1):

To check if there are at least 5 words in string:

```
(?:\w+\W+){4}\b
```

- `(?:\w+\W+){4}` 4 words separated by non [word characters](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html)
- `\b` followed by a [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) -> **requires** a 5th word

[See demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/HH2aqQ/1)