# Google Apps Script - Count words contributed by user in a google doc

Tags: google-apps-script

Is there a method for counting words contributed by user in a Google Doc?  Can't seem to find anything in their docs, but maybe there is a hacky way to do it?

Comment: Take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35056771/count-number-of-words-in-a-string)

Answer (score 0):

Based from this [forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/KrDBVk4EmTU), *unfortunately, there currently isn't any way to get the word count of individual contributors to a document. If the students have "Comment" permissions (rather than "Edit" permissions), their contributions would be tracked so you could see which person added which part of the content. However, even then there wouldn't be a way to add up the number of words contributed.*